# AWS API - Start new instance within an Auto-Scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I would like to start a new instance inside an Auto-Scaling group so the new instance will be 100% identical to other instances in this group.
In other words I want to do the same thing AWS does when scaling rules are triggered.

What API method I need to call to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the DescribeAutoScalingGroups API and the SetDesiredCapacity API.

**Pseudocode:**

- Call [DescribeAutoScalingGroups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAutoScalingGroups.html) to get the current desired size of your group.
- Call [SetDesiredCapacity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_SetDesiredCapacity.html), setting `DesiredCapacity = CurrentDesiredCapacity + 1`

SetDesiredCapacity allows you to change the "desired capacity" of an AutoScaling group. If you increase the current desired capacity by 1, the AutoScaling Group will launch a new instance based on the [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) associated with your [launch configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html). This is what scaling policies do within the bounds of your min/max capacity.

**SetDesiredCapacity API Example:** (from docs)

```
https://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/?Action=SetDesiredCapacity
&AutoScalingGroupName=my-asg
&HonorCooldown=false
&DesiredCapacity=2
&Version=2011-01-01
&AUTHPARAMS
```

**set-desired-capacity CLI Example:** (from docs)

```
aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name my-auto-scaling-group --desired-capacity 2 --no-honor-cooldown
```

**Reference:**

- [AWS Documentation - Manual Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-manual-scaling.html)
- [API - SetDesiredCapacity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_SetDesiredCapacity.html)
- [CLI - set-desired-capacity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/set-desired-capacity.html)